# Hbase/HDFS Jmeter test performnace in hadoop 3.3.6

Tags: hadoop, jmeter-plugins

I want to test performance on hdfs using jmeter on hadoop 3.3.6, but the hbase / hdfs plugin is not supported on hadoop 3.3.6, I have seen tutorials and several ways, namely by changing dependencies on pom.xml or .pom. but the problem is that I don't know where the pom.xml or .pom file is located on hadoop 3.3.6 and how to execute it, please help, in addition I am using ubuntu 18.

Answer (score 0):

The pom.xml is [here](https://github.com/undera/jmeter-hadoop/blob/master/pom.xml)

Once you get the code and make the changes you want you will need to compile the plugin using [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html) and replace the .jar file in lib/ext folder of your JMeter installation with the one from the "target" folder of the compiled plugin.

Alternative option is using [JSR223 Sampler and Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy) and write your Hadoop performance test logic without installing any 3rd-party plugins